# Using Bootstrap to a Specific Component for Offcanvas Usage Without Affecting the Overall Layout

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, import

Yo Guys,

I'm working on a react project where I've already set up a solid layout. Then, I added Bootstrap to implement an offcanvas component, and it works well. However, I encountered an issue when I imported the Bootstrap CSS:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This import is messing the overall layout of my project (eg. different font boldness, font family). I'm wondering if there's a way to selectively use Bootstrap only within the specific component where I need it or if i could import just the Offcanvas part of Bootstrap.

I've attempted to customize Bootstrap, but I couldn't the bootstrap component on the v3 customization website and i dont know how to do it in v4 and v5.

Any advice or guidance on how to isolate Bootstrap to the offcanvas component or address the layout issue would be greatly appreciated.